# Empty greyish screen when i install flutter app on real device

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

I just finished a flutter project and used flutter build apk --split-per-abi to generate an apk to test on actual device, after successfully building, app shows nothing but an empty greyish screen. What could have gone wrong ?, app worked well all through development even last test before the build

NB: all pre-build test were done through chrome(emulator seems to distort my laptop),  but packages used were also configured properly for mobile too.

I'll appreciate any help and if you'll need to see the project for your self,  just email me I'll share it with you. Email: wilsonoguchi100@gmail.com

Comment: run `flutter build apk --release` to get a fat apk for all abis

Answer (score 1):

Empty greyish screen appears on flutter app releases when an error occurs. Given that there were no problems during your testing the simplest thing to do are:

1. Check if the device has internet connection or better yet check the android manifest if internet permission is present.
2. If you're still experiencing problems on your emulator. Try to use USB debugging on your real device and run your flutter app on debug mode.